# How to Mock Parent class for Unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

So I have three classes: A, B, C. I need to write unit tests for class `A`.

```
  class A extends B{
   //fields go here ...

   public A(String string, ...){
      super.(string,...);
   }
   //other methods here ...
 }

 class B{
   C stuff;
   //other stuff
 }
```

So `C` is an important resource (like JDBC or ssh Session). Naturally, I am mocking `C`. How do I mock `B`. Imagine `B` has many children classes that extends it.

My main problem is that `A` is calling `super.(...)`. I don't want to inject methods into `A` just for testing. To me that's bad design. Any ideas how to mock the parent?

For example I cannot do `class MockB extends B{...}` and then try `MockB obj = new A();` This would not work because both `MockB` and `A` would be children of `B`.

Comment: Yes, I am. Thanks for any insight. Also C is resource from another package.

Comment: How is C constructed? I'd look at adding a new ctor on B & A that took a C.

Answer (score 11):

You really shouldn't try to mock the superclass of the class under test.  While some mocking frameworks allow "partial mocks" that might make it possible to partially mock the class you're actually testing, it's a bad idea.

If class `A` and the relation between `A` and `B` are sufficiently complex that you think you need this, they should probably not be in an inheritance relation at all.

Consider changing your code so that `B` delegates to `A` instead of extending it.

Comment: I am testing pre-existing code. I am not sure I am allowed to refactor. But thanks for input, though. +1

Answer (score 3):

you want to mock B class which means you are probably not testing B nor A. so why do you care if it calls super, foo, bar or other methods? do you know how many methods jdbc calls? but as you said, you have no problem with mocking it. same here. you just do

```
B mockOfB = Mockito.mock(B.class);
```

that's it. you have a mock of B and you can test any invocations you like.

if you are testing A so why you can't simply instantiate it? does constructor of B require some static dependencies? in this case you should refactor it or use something like powermock (if you really can't refactor the class). if you can't instantiate B because it is abstract then just extend it in your test

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. I am trying to test `A`.

Comment: Having the Junit test extending `B` sounds quite novel and wrong. +1 for thinking outside the box. But that's a strange concept.

Comment: actually it's nothing new. it's common practice to extends the class you are testing. this way you have access to protected variables from the all inherited classes without need of reflection